# how to make line break based on the div width and should not break the word if it is not a long word in css

Tags: css, word-break

I need the line break in the div based on div width. div width is dynamic. Word should not break if it is not a long word.

I used **word-break:break-all** and **word-wrap:break-word**. Lines are break as we expect, but word are also break. But we doesn't not break the word.

Please find the attached image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJesQ.png

Comment: Don't add any word break property, sentence will break on white-spaces

Comment: I need to break the line or long word based on the div width. because I used word break

Comment: Show a real example and explain exactly how the text should be wrapped. In particular, which long words should wrap and how?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Please see the sample content in image http://i.stack.imgur.com/xJesQ.png. I need to use word-break because of long words. And words should wrap if it is longer than the div, should not wrap, if it is a small word.

Answer (score 0):

try using css bootstrap scaffolding or responsive columns
you can also try to make css of div to

```
width: 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `word-wrap:break-word` -

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Uj9hB/)**

This way, only words that are wider than the full container width will break.

Comment: used this also. but the words are break. Need  and used also word-break.

Comment: I don't understand what you need. What is wrong with this? Look at the demo and you will see that only words that are wider than the full width will break.

Comment: Use word-break:break-all; in that demo see what happen. words are break.

Comment: Why MUST you use `word-break:break-all;` ??? This is exactly what is causing your problem!?

Comment: must use word-break, because I need to break the line or long word based on the div width

Comment: @VasanthNedunchezhiyan as everybody tries to say and as the demo shows: use only `word-wrap` and not `word-break` and you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah It is working now. I using table inside the div which have one `<tr>` and one `<td>` like `<div> <table style="table-layout: fixed;width: 100%;word-wrap: break-word;"><tr><td> ....content.... </td></tr></table> </div>`. Now the line break working based on the div width and also break the word if it is not a long word.

Comment: this is for sure not an elegant solution.